# How to remove highlight from text containing onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I am using displaying this html code in webView for windows phone 8.1, which uses IE 11 I guess.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <p><font size="4">
    <span id="1" onclick=notify(1)>Man this is awkward.</span>
    <span id="2" onclick=notify(2)> Why is everyone so quite today.</span>
    <span id="3" onclick=notify(3)> Oh please someone talk to me.</span>
    <span id="4" onclick=notify(4)> This silence is intimidating.</span>
    <br><br><br><br></font></p><style>

                    body {
                      -webkit-user-select: none;
                         -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
                          -ms-user-select: none;
                              user-select: none;
                    }
                    </style><script>
                    function notify(val)
                    {
                         window.external.notify(val.toString());
                    } 
                    </script></body></html>
```

But when I click on any of the lines, the whole line gets selected like this.[image]

I want to remove this highlight. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Will this page be viewed on IE11 only or other mobile browsers as well?

Answer (score 1):

### CSS

```
outline-style: none; 
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

### JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);
```

And what touchstart does:

```
$('body').live(
'touchstart', 
function(e){
    if(e.target.localName != 'select'){
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

If thats not working, check [this](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/06/04/getting-rid-of-the-gray-box-in-phonegap-for-windows-phone/). Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please tell what the javascript code is doing?

Comment: check this for info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: nope, this is not working, I'll go through the link.

Comment: @ac-lab you can also try `document.getElementById("4").style.webkitTapHighlightColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";`

Comment: @ac-lab Ohh, make sure you’re putting separate `:hover`, `:focus` and `:active` styles on the element you remove the `outline`, `-webkit-touch-callout: none;` and `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` from. Maybe it can fix the problem.